# Cannot GET/ portfolio.ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I have main page with link in it. When I am trying to open link 'porfolio.ejs' I get page with the message "Cannot GET/portfolio.ejs"
Here is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('mainpage');
});

app.get('/portfolio', function(request, response) {
  response.render('portfolio');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: the portfolio.ejs file is not reachable. Check that it is in the same folder as the index.js

Comment: the file is in same folder as index.ejs in views folder

Comment: change the link from `portfolio.ejs` to `portfolio`

Comment: I have another issue now. I can't get to main page now from portfolio.ejs. I changed the link form mainpage.ejs to mainpage

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: Same error Cannot GET / mainpage

Comment: why are you requesting for `mainpage` .  there is no routes directing to `/mainpage` the `/` is directing to mainpage so just request for `/`. Got it? This should solve your problem. I will add this as the answer later.